# Tab menu using prime ng

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, primeng

```
<p-tabMenu class="ui-tabmenu" [model]="items"></p-tabMenu>

this.items = [    
       { label: 'Notes', icon: 'fa-file-o', url: ['Page1'] },
        { label: 'Companies', icon: 'fa-edit', url: ['Page2'] },
        { label: 'Google', icon: 'fa-plus', url: 'http://www.google.com' }
    ];
```

my code shows the following error in console.

EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:35:4 caused by: No provider for Router!

ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Router!

how to resolve this issue.?

Answer (score 0):

In your routing have you used like this.

```
const routes:  @Routes([
      {path: '/crisis-center', component: CrisisListComponent},
      {path: '/heroes',        component: HeroListComponent}
    ])

import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Comment: No provider for Router : Is only based on Routing Issues